# drill through from power bi card

Tags: charts, powerbi, drillthrough

I need some help with drill through. I have a main dashboard with high level aggregated data. I need to drill through to a details report I have created with more granular data. The chart type I have used in the dashboard is a CARD, to which it should drill down from. Only thing is when I right click it does not give the drill option. I have added the relevant field into the details report but still no rightclick --> drill through. Any advice would be great. Could this be a limitation with Power BI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree that it's poor form not to have this sort of functionality.  I've tried multiple workarounds, using other visualisations without success.  The only thing that i can get to work is to have the card, and overlay a button on top of it (making sure that the button is transparent), which links to a bookmark on that page that i want to 'drill through' to.

Comment: This is actually the best solution

Answer (score 1):

I would change from the Card visual to a Table visual. After setting the Format properties you can achieve a similar look to a Card.  And if you are show the right fields, then you can right-click and drill down.